# Asp button tried to call itself again after 10 minutes on server

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp button.I am calculating some data and insert them in database.It works fine locally but on server when data is big than it tried to call itself again after ten minutes. I don't know the reason why this is happening.

This is aspx side button:

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSimulate" Style="width: 90px; display: none;" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="javascript:return fncChkSelect(MainContent_gvSimulationdata,'chkselect');" />
```

Server side code is as follows:

```
   Protected Sub btnSimulate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSimulate.Click
    Try
        Dim dtSimtable As New DataTable
        IsSavedSimulation = True
        dtSimtable = obj.GetEsistingSimulationCriteriaID(ViewState("recentSimulationCriteriaId"), Session("ID"))
        If dtSimtable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            fncInsertUpdate()
        Else
            Dim IsDeleted As Int32
            IsDeleted = obj.fncDeleteSimulatedRecord_Error(ViewState("recentSimulationCriteriaId"))
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "Script", "fncHideLoading('" & lblErrorMsg & "');", True)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

All your answers are most welcome.

Comment: whatever is causing the function to run again, it's not in the code you've posted. Try and debug it some more and see if there is another relevant place in your code where this could be triggered. Perhaps some javascript has an interval set to run the button click again, or perhaps there's something in the VB code which causes it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have check again but this button is not triggered from anywhere. Problem is when i uploaded the code on server. It work fine locally.

Comment: In that case look for differences in the deployed environment. We can't see any of that, so hard to help you

Comment: I am getting data from a gridview which are in update panel and the button is placed outside the update panel.

Comment: I am checking deployment environment. Thanks for assisting.

Comment: Is it possible that it could be a window timer timeout problem?

Comment: Depends if you've got timeout code, what it's for and how you're using it. I can't see that so I can't really comment in detail.

Comment: Is there any Server property which has timeout property and by default time is 10 minutes.

Comment: No I meant a Javascript timer code (not session timeout), sorry. You mentioned if it could be a window timer problem. Therefore I assumed you might have some timer code which you could show us.